# Bamboo - no tests found - Bamboo not finding any tests in the configured job

Tags: maven, configuration, continuous-integration, bamboo

the cloned Bamboo plan not finding any of maven tests for the new metafilter. I have checked all variables and could not find anything incorrect. Please help.
The message on the plan was 'No tests found'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved. My Bad, I had compilation errors in the build.
I think I did not check the logs at the plan level.
The Bamboo log created at the job level had only a one line message that the build failed.